# Spring Data Mongo with Kotlin error: "must be a compile-time constant"

Tags: mongodb, kotlin, spring-data

I am trying to create a Spring Data Mongo Query with **Kotlin** in my ReactiveCrudRepository:

```
@Query("{ 'contacts': { $in: ?0 } }")
fun isInContacts(aContact: String): Flux<User>
```

However, I am getting a compile error:

```
"An annotation parameter must be a compile-time constant"
"Keyword cannot be used as a reference"
```

How to solve this problem?

Does it have something to do with the `$`. Since its used in Strings to reference a variable?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Does it have something to do with the $. Since its used in Strings to reference a variable?

Yes, it does, and `in` is a reserved word in Kotlin, which is why you get the error `Keyword cannot be used as a reference`. You must escape the dollar sign to remove its special meaning:

```
@Query("{ 'contacts': { \$in: ?0 } }")
```